Proxmox nfs: server not responding; timed out
I’ve set up a Magento2 test environment using several LXC containers. The central component of this environment is a privileged LXC container that acts as an NFS storage server, providing images and other resources accessed by other containers.
The setup and communication generally work well, but I’m receiving the following error almost every second:
kernel: nfs: server X.X.X.243 not responding, timed out
The container with the IP address ending in .243 is the NFS server. Interestingly, the error message still appears even when this LXC container is either shut down or completely removed from the host. Additionally, all other LXC containers using the NFS mount are powered down, so they shouldn’t be causing any error messages either.
Is there a way to identify the cause of this error message?
On the PVE host, I’ve already checked /etc/fstab to see if there is any mount entry referencing the LXC NFS server. I’ve also tried using the following commands to search for any open connections or mounts pointing to the IP X.X.X.243:
lsof | grep X.X.X.243
mount | grep X.X.X.243

Since I don’t have physical access to the host, I’d prefer to avoid rebooting the entire host. Any solutions that can avoid a restart would be greatly appreciated. :/
TL;DR:
I’m receiving an error message indicating that the NFS server at IP X.X.X.243 is unreachable, even though no LXC container with that IP exists anymore and there are no relevant mounts or entries on the host. I have to find the root cause, which process permanently tries to reach nfs server X.X.X.243

LXC container that acts as an NFS storage server — I see a problem here. While it's not forbidden, I'd stay away from using any uncommon kernel resources in containers, and standard NFS server is a kernel server. This is the same suggestion as, don't use FUSE in containers, don't mount network filesystems (better mount them at the host and then bind, if you need that access in the container). Try userspace NFS server (like nfs-ganesha), if you must, but still I think any configuration where host depends somehow on its own guest is unreasonable.

Thank you for your response @NikitaKipriyanov. You concerns are totally right, but this environment currently takes place in a dmz, which has no possible contact to the world wide web. I just wanted to test the differences between container based and vm based magento2 environment.
